# Remoting from Windows Server 2012 64 bit to Windows Server 2008 R1

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, installation, remoting

We need to upgrade our servers which run Windows Server 2008 R1 (32 bit version) to Windows Server 2012 (64 bit version).

Some old components are not supported in Windows Server 2012.

Is it possible to invoke the old components (located on Windows Server 2008 R1) from the new Windows 2012 server via remoting?

Has anyone done something similar?

Comment: Why would anyone make a decision to upgrade to 2012 R2 if there are compatibility issues? The logical choices are remain on 2008 R1 x86 (which is not secure), or replace the "old components" with something that works correctly on a modern operating system. Trying to find a special snowflake solution just because you can usually creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: Pretty much what Greg Askew said.  You might be able to find a way to copy the components to a new server in an unsupported way, but I wouldn't trust it for production use.

Comment: What components are you referring to?

Comment: @user2320464 old com+ components

Comment: It really depends on if they're remotely accessible. You'd have to reconfigure them to be remotely accessible and configure the app to connect remotely instead of via localhost. Since you're questioning this upgrade to begin with, I would advise to not do it. Server 2008 will not EOL for awhile which gives you plenty of time to plan a proper upgrade by engaging the developer and/or vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from Server 2008 x86 to Server 2012 is not possible.

According the supported upgrade paths document for Server 2008 R2 (which is the most recent doc to mention Server 2008), ["Cross-architecture in-place upgrades (for example, x86 to x64) are not supported."](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979563(v=ws.10).aspx)  According to the supported upgrade paths document for Server 2012 R2, ["Cross-architecture in-place upgrades (for example, x86 to x64) are not supported."](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303416(v=ws.11).aspx)

I believe the problem is that "Cross-architecture in-place upgrades (for example, x86 to x64) are not supported."  You'll have to install Server 2012 as a new OS, which is probably what you should be doing anyway.

If you're talking about leaving the old servers in place and "controlling" them remotely from the new server (which you seem to ask about, despite the fact that this is contradictory to the statement you made about upgrading), that's probably possible, but a horrible idea.  Just reimage the servers.